# 8051 ADXL SPI interfacing

Tags: c, spi, 8051

I am trying to interface a ADXL345 to 8051 - AT89C51RC2 through SPI interface.

I have used the below code taken from [here](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc4348.pdf):

```
 include "Init.h"

 define SS_ADXL P1_0;

 void SPI_interr_routine(void);

 char serial_data;

 char data_example;

 char data_save;

 char transmit_completed;


void main(void)
{

    // Insert code
    Hardware_init();
    transmit_completed = 0;
    data_example=0x55;
    data_save = 0;
    printf("\n\r1111111111111");
    SPCON |= 0x10; /* Master mode */
    P1_1=1; /* enable master */
    SPCON |= 0x82; /* Fclk Periph/128 */
    SPCON &= ~0x08; /* CPOL=0; transmit mode example */
    SPCON |= 0x04; /* CPHA=1; transmit mode example */
    IEN1 |= 0x04; /* enable spi interrupt */
    SPCON |= 0x40; /* run spi */
    P1_1 = 0;
    EA=1; /* enable interrupts */
    //while(1) /* endless */
    //{
        SS_ADXL = 0;
        SPDAT= (0x32 | 0x80); /* send an example data */ //
        while(!transmit_completed);/* wait end of transmition */
        transmit_completed = 0; /* clear software transfert flag */

        SPDAT=0x00; /* data is send to generate SCK signal */
        while(!transmit_completed);/* wait end of transmition */
        transmit_completed = 0; /* clear software transfert flag */
        data_save = serial_data; /* save receive data */
        SS_ADXL = 1;
    //}

    printf("\n\r%c data_save = " , data_save);
}


void it_SPI(void) __interrupt (9) 
{

   SPI_interr_routine();

   return;

}

void SPI_interr_routine(void)
{

    if((SPSTA & 0x80) == 1)
    {
        serial_data = SPDAT;
        transmit_completed=1;
    }

    return;
}
```

Hardware Connections :

I have used [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009) logic level converter  to connect the 8051 to ADXL345.

P1.1 (SS) pin of 8051 is unconnected and I am enabling it in software by setting P1.1 to 1.

The CS pin of ADXL345 is connected to a GPIO of 8051 and I am selecting the slave (ADXL345) by setting the GPIO pin to low before writing / reading and then setting it high.
I am using the inbuilt SPI module in 8051.

When I run the above code, the SPIF bit is not getting set.

please let me know if anything is wrong with the hardware connection or the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [ADXL345 Datasheet Rev E page 15](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL345.pdf#page=15) states "the timing scheme follows clock polarity (CPOL) = 1 and clock phase (CPHA) = 1". Make *absolutely sure* none of the timing limitations are violated. This chip in particular must follow the minimum and maximum timings shown on page 17. A digital-storage oscilloscope (preferred) or logic analyzer may be very helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks. But I am using the inbuilt SPI module. So I thought, the timing requirements are taken care of by the controller itself when I initialize SPI and write to SPDAT.

Comment: In the code, it reads: `SPCON &= ~0x08; /* CPOL=0; transmit mode example */`. I like to think of SPI less as a "module", and more like a can of worms. It *seems* simple, but oh, the details! :)